# 30amp power cord to 20amp breaker?

Tags: wiring, switch, circuit-breaker

I am converting a cargo trailer into a camping trailer, including wiring it to have power from and RV hookup.  The most common RV hookup is a 30amp.  Since i don't really need the 30amp power, my plan is to run the 30amp power cord to a load center with a couple 20amp breakers, then run 12/2 wire to 20amp receptacles and light switches.

Does that sound correct?  Am i missing something that would make this setup dangerous in any way?

Comment: Sounds about right to me.

Comment: Your breakers shouldn't exceed to input capacity. So your load centre is 40amp capacity but your supply is 30a. It's not about that you know you never exceed it. It's for others who don't know. Or in case for some reason you do.

Comment: @ppumkin, can you clarify what you mean. The capacity isn't based on the sum of the breakers in the load center. If that was the case pretty much every home in US is dangerously overloaded.

Comment: It sounds like you'll provide a cord that is rated for 30A and feed a load center in the trailer which will have a couple 20A breakers; is that right? If so, then yes it's fine assuming there's either a main breaker in the trailer rated for 30A or what feeds it in the RV is fused/breaker to protect the circuit. Obviously, if you have two 20A breakers you'll be able to pull *that* load, if there's nothing protecting the wired between the two.

Comment: Yea that is what I meant, what Chief said. I thought you had 2 20A connected directly to 30A without any breaker, or usually a higher breaker on the 30A side. You shuoud use 30A or better ratted cable (for future expansion) on the 30A breaker. All these regualtions are different everywhere, but we always used to put a rated main breaker, say 30A, then distribute that to sub breakers, even if its slightly more. If that ever happens the Main breaker(next to the sub breakers) will trip. For new builds technically sub breakers shouldn't exceed the main breaker. What happens later is another story.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know if you ever got a proper answer.
Yes putting 2 20 amp breakers on a 30 amp service is fine. You will trip the 30 amp main if you draw more than 30 for any length of time.
We over subscribe breaker panels all the time you should plan on your peak load being 80% by code but you can have more total breakers than the service rating.